# Migrate from an early 2015 MacBook Pro running Catalina to a 2019 MacBook Air running Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, migration

- I have one early 2015 MacBook Pro currently running Catalina 10.15. That’s my production machine;
- I got a new 2019 MacBook Air which I want to make my main production machine; The Macbook Air is from summer 2019 and came brand new with Mojave installed;

Is there a way for me to migrate from Catalina to Mojave, using either the Migration Assistant or a TimeMachine backup? If I a restore from a TimeMachine backup, won’t it also restore the Catalina version of macOS on the new MacBook Air?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate to another MacOS version you only need to copy over your home folder and `/Applications` (excluding the pre-installed MacOS apps).

You can use any backup tool such as Time Machine or `rsync` ([here](https://gist.github.com/glowinthedark/8d8879735f8cb6cc45d90c415ee15cfb) is an example).

For Time Machine, go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Time Machine</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> and add the folders to exclude from the backup.

You can click the <kbd>+</kbd> button or drag the folders from Finder into the excluded list. To avoid backing up the operating system drag `/System`, `/Library`, `/opt` and `/usr`.

If you use homebrew it's probably better to configure it from scratch on a new machine. It might be useful to generate a list of current brew packages with `brew list` and `brew cask list`. Then you can reinstall all your brew packages with `brew install < mypackages.txt` and `brew cask install < mycaskpackages.txt` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259627/time-machine-restore-newer-mac-to-older-mac)

Anyway you should be fine as long as you only import data, e.g. desktop, documents, downloads, etc.  I would not try to carry over ~/Library folder, as this may contain items that are only relevant to the 'newer' version of macOS.  You should probably separately export Apple Mail and re-import as well.

That being said... why don't you just first update the 2019 to 10.15 then directly import your time machine and not worry about incompatibilities?

Comment: Thank you for pointing the previously answered question: it’s also very useful. Catalina (10.15) comes with issues, I’ve found. I would rather work with a previous, stable operating system for a while.